# 2つの実数を昇順に並べるプログラム

Tags: c

はじめに、関数`swapd`を用いて，2つの実数値を小さいほうから`*num1`, `*num2`に格納しなおす 関数`sort2`を作成。その後，`sort2`を呼び出した上で，その結果を用いて実行例のように表示するプログラムを作成。

このような手順でプログラムを書きたいのですが、書き方がわかりません。

関数`swapd`で値の交換を行い、`sort2`ではその呼び出し（昇順に並べたいので`num1>num2`のときは`swapd(num1,num2)`と呼び出し、`num2>num1`のときは`swapd(num2,num1)`と呼び出すと思いました）をしたいのですが、どんな値を入力しても値が交換して出力されてしまいました。`sort2`での呼び出し方が間違っているのだとは思いましたが、どこが間違っているのかがわかりませんでした。（他にも間違っているかもしれません）

**実行結果**

```
$./a.out 
Input n1: 15.9
Input n2: 11.1
Before Sorting
n1: 15.900000  :  n2: 11.100000  
After Sorting
n1: 11.100000  :  n2: 12.200000
```

**ソースコード**

```c
void swapd_double(double *num1,double *num2)
{
    double tmp;
    tmp=*num1;
    *num1=*num2;
    *num2=tmp;
}
void sort2(double *num1,double *num2)
{
    if(num1>num2){
     return swapd_double(num1,num2);
    } else if(num2>num1) {
        return swapd_double(num2,num1);
    }
}

double main(void)
{
    double num1,num2;
    printf("Input n1: ");
    scanf("%lf",&num1);
    printf("Input n2: ");
    scanf("%lf",&num2);

    printf("Before Sorting\nn1:%f,n2:%f\n",num1,num2);
    sort2(&num1,&num2);
    printf("After Sorting\nn1:%f,n2:%f\n",num1,num2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: タイトルと本文 (3つ と 2つ)、説明とソースコード (`swapd` と`swapd_double`) で食い違っている箇所がいくつもあるようです。

Comment: 元々`num1`が小さいなら、何もしなければ良い(というか何かしてはいけない)わけです。

Comment: 関数swapdは関数swapd_doubleの意味で言ったつもりでした。説明不足ですみません。

Answer (score 1):

「num1とnum2の値を入れ替える」の結果と「num2とnum1の値を入れ替える」の結果は同じです。したがって以下のコードだとif文のどちらに分岐しようが同じことをしています。

```
if (num1 > num2){
    return swapd_double(num1, num2);
} else if(num2 > num1) {
    return swapd_double(num2, num1);
}
```

いまやりたいのはnum1 <= num2となるように整列させることです。つまり、最初からnum1 <= num2であった場合は何もする必要がありません。num2 < num1のときだけ入れ替える必要があります。よって下のような形のコードになります。

```
if (num2 < num1) {
    // ここでnum1とnum2を入れ替える
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

swapd_doubleという関数は、swapd_double(num1, num2);と書いてもswapd_double(num2, num1);と書いても、２つを入れ替えるという意味ですよね。ですからnum1とnum2が同じ時以外は必ず入れ替わります。